# Castle DynamicProxy2: Get the Target inside an Interceptor?

Tags: target, castle-dynamicproxy, iinterceptor

I'm using Castle DynamicProxy2 to "tack on" interfaces to retrieve fields from a dictionary.  For example, given the following class:

```
public class DataContainer : IDataContainer
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _Fields = null;

    public Dictionary<string, object> Data
    {
        get { return _Fields ?? (_Fields = new Dictionary<string, object>()); }
    }
}
```

I want to use the following interface as an interface proxy to extract the "Name" value out of the Fields dictionary:

```
public interface IContrivedExample
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

From an interceptor, I want to get the "target" DataContainer, and return the "Name" value:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    object fieldName = omitted; // get field name based on invocation information

    DataContainer container = ???; // this is what I'm trying to figure out
    invocation.ReturnValue = container.Fields[fieldName];
}

// Somewhere in code
var c = new DataContainer();
c.Fields.Add("Name", "Jordan");

var pg = new ProxyGenerator();
IContrivedExample ice = (IContrivedExample) pg.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(..., c, ...);
Debug.Assert(ice.Name == "Jordan");
```

Any thoughts on how to get the underlying target

Note: this is a contrived example I'm using to establish some context around the question I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  You have to cast the Proxy to IProxyTargetAccessor:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    object fieldName = omitted; // get field name based on invocation information

    var accessor = invocation.Proxy as IProxyTargetAccessor;

    DataContainer container = (DataContainer) accessor.DynProxyGetTarget();
    invocation.ReturnValue = container.Fields[fieldName];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why the hassle?

use

```
var container = invocation.InvocationTarget as DataContainer;
```

BTW, IIUC, you're trying to implement what is already provided by [Castle DictionaryAdapter](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dictionaryadapter.md). Why not use what's already out there?

Comment: Initially, I tried casting the InvocationTarget as a DataContainer and that did not work.  That is what lead me to using IProxyTargetAccessor.

As for the DictionaryAdapter 1) I didn't know it existed and 2) I have other properties on the "DataContainer" than just Fields.  I ommited that because it wasn't relevant to the question I was asking.

Thanks!